# ERROR ITMS-90208: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle <your.app> does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist"

Tags: ios, xcode

I've started getting this error message from Xcode:

> ERROR ITMS-90208: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle <your.app> does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist"

I've never specified the OS version number in the plist. It's always in the Deployment Target settings. I've checked the version in Deployment Target but it all looks good.

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: I am getting the same and I think that this might be something to do with workaround on how to make stuff work in older iOS versions ... enclosing new code in if statements, etc ... :( ... and obviously XCode finding it ..

Comment: Same solution from your other question works:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518826/error-itms-90092-this-bundle-is-invalid-apps-that-include-an-arm64-architectu

Comment: @Snow Crash What did you do to fix the issue? Thanks

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? and how?

Comment: I got bitten by this error as well. The weird thing is that the app launches fine in local builds, and internal release builds. Is there a way for me to check if a binary supports a particular version? Asked this question in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/586519/9129 as well.

Comment: See this solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64318182)

Answer (score 76):

Go Runner -> Flutter -> AppFrameworkInfo.plist

And change the minimum sdk version 9 and also on xcode minimum sdk version 9.0

It's work for me :)

Comment: I hate apple guys, Why I have to change this number in two places. the runner file itself and `AppFrameworkInfo.plist` and the surprise that It doesn't give you this error in an early stage of publishing. No .. you have to build release and archive your project and upload it then you got the fishy error!

Comment: @ShadyMohamedSherif it's a Flutter (Google) thing, not Apple.

Comment: What I did is I'd make sure that my podfile and AppFrameworkInfo.plist is the same version and it Works

Answer (score 27):

I added to the `Info.plist` xml:

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>10.0</string>
```

and it worked.

Comment: It has to be add in AppFrameworkInfo.plist not project Info.plist

Answer (score 21):

I added iOS version to 10.0 in different places:

- Runner -> Runner -> General -> Deployment info: Target
- Runner -> Runner -> info.plist
- Runner -> Flutter -> AppFrameworkInfo.plist

Worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

I do the development in Flutter and I got this error when I validated my app today.
I did the following 3 steps to solve the problem.

1. Open flutter_project/ios/Podfile file. Add this at the top `platform :ios, '9.0'`
2. Xcode -> Runner -> General -> Deployment Info -> Target: `iOS 9.0`
3. Xcode -> Runner -> Flutter -> MinimumOSVersion: `9.0`

Answer (score 17):

I hate to add another answer when there are so many, but none of the others worked, and this did :

After doing a `flutter clean`, changing **MinimumOSVersion** (inside /ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist) to 9.0, **iOS Deployment Target** (inside **project** runner) to 9.0 and **iOS Deployment Target** (inside **target** runner) to 9.0 the error disappeared.

(from : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58200#issuecomment-675085313)

All the existing answers are missing the change inside of Xcode > Runner > **Project** > Runner.

Answer (score 12):

Most important is to add this to your podfile

```
 platform :ios, '13.0'
```

Then change MinimumOSVersion to 13.0 in

```
Runner -> Flutter -> AppFrameworkInfo.plist
```

Then in your xcode => General => Deployment info. IOS=>13.0

Answer (score 11):

To help others who might come across this question. There is a variation of this error with the same code but slightly different message:

> ERROR ITMS-90208: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle
>   YourApp.app/Frameworks/SomeFramework.framework does not support
>   the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist.“

Even though the app's Info.plist had a MinimumSdk setting of 10.0 and the framework's Info.plist had a MinimumSdk setting of 8.0 (which to me seems to be a suitable combination), uploading via the Application Loader gave the above error.

It was fixed by *increasing* the MinimumSdk setting in the framework's Info.plist file to 10.0, the same value that the app was using. This was the only change and fixed the submission error.

Comment: Thanks. This save my day.

Answer (score 9):

I added first into the info.plist

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>13.0</string>
```

And after I changed the AppFrameworkinfo.plist
Must be 13.0
[image]

Also, I close the project and reopen

Comment: Nice visual support

Answer (score 8):

In my case I use flutter not stable version (v2.6.0-11.0.pre) and found this issue.

And then I downgrade to stable version (v2.5.3) and follow below:

First step: run this in terminal

```
$ flutter clean
```

Second step: open file `Runner -> Flutter -> AppFrameworkInfo.plist` and set

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>9.0</string>
```

Third step: Check every ware about iOS Deployment Target and set 9.0

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Fourth step: `Clean Build Folder` before `Archive` In Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that the Bundle was missing the Launch Images for iPhone iOS 6,7.

Most frustrating error in a long time as the message does not hint anything and you are alone finding what might be wrong.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

My Project minumum sdk was 8.0...
It seems that Flutter need higher deployment target..
It is solved when I set "10.0"

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
Modify /ios/Flutter/AppframeworkInfo.plistto MinimumOSVersion9.0, then modify the iOS Deployment Target of the project to 9.0, modify the version of the corresponding Podfile, and then flutter cleanrepackage and upload

**Solution 2:**
Modify flutter sdkthe corresponding file below, change the MinimumOSVersionvalue inside to 9.0, and then flutter clean repackage and upload

bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios-release/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/Flutter.framework/Info.plist

bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios-release/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/Flutter .framework/Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a problem in my deployment info. The deployment targets were different in my .app and .appex extension lists when they didn't automatically sync up. Once they were changed to the same value everything ran smoothly. This is just a fix I found for sticker pack projects on Xcode 8. Hope it helps in any way

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact problem when using a beta version of Xcode to submit to the App Store. Using the release version resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change target  version in General section Deployment info

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by just adding below snippet to podFile

```
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix the persistent issue I've been facing across all my projects for the past 3 days. For those experiencing similar challenges, here's the solution that worked for me:

- Downgrade Xcode Version: Initially, I was using the latest Xcode version (15.3), but I found that downgrading to an older version resolved the problem. I uninstalled Xcode 15.3 and installed version 15.1 instead.
- You can download older versions of Xcode from this link(https://xcodereleases.com).
- Resolve Package Dependency Issue: After downgrading Xcode, I addressed any package dependency issues that arose as a result of the version change.
- If you encounter package dependency issues with your SDK packages, you can find helpful guidance on resolving them here
  ([Package.resolved file is corrupted or malformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67185817/package-resolved-file-is-corrupted-or-malformed)).

I hope this solution proves helpful for others facing similar challenges.
Best regards,
Krishan Pahadiya

Comment: Its good answer. If you use xcode 15.3, you shoould use xcode 15.2. Because sdk developers haven't managed to solve this problem yet.
For comfortable movement between xcode versions, I recommend using the "Xcodes" app

Answer (score 0):

*Non-Flutter Solution:*

For me, I was getting this error for Google libraries (via SPM) when I ran the build from XCode Cloud. Weirdly, it worked fine when I built locally even though both XCC and my local XCode were the same version (15.3). After some trial and error, it seems like there's some sort of breaking change in XCode 15.3, and it's not backwards compatible with old package versions.

**TL;DR: make sure all your google packages are the latest version (e.g. GTM, Firebase, Mobile Ads, etc).**