# ERROR ITMS-90092: “This bundle is invalid. Apps that include an arm64 architecture are required to include an armv7 architecture.”

Tags: xcode, armv7

I'm getting a few errors submitting an app.

Any idea how you fix this error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90092: “This bundle is invalid. Apps that include an arm64 architecture are required to include an armv7 architecture.”
```

Looking in Valid Architectures in Xcode I see armv7 listed. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured out how to bypass this error and successfully submit my app. Here is what you have to do if you already have armv7 included under build settings > valid architectures:

1. Run the app on your phone with the usb cord pugged into the computer.
2. Once the app has successfully played on your phone, unplug your phone.
3. Now go to product > archive > validate
4. Once you have done this, click submit to app store and your app should submit just fine.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Why do we need to unplug the device when archiving?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your `Scheme`, `Archive` is pointing to `Release`, and that your `Build Active Architecture` for `Release` is `No` also.

1. Click Edit Scheme.

[image: Click Edit Scheme]

2. Set Archive to Release.

[image: Set Archive to Release]

3. Set Build Active Architecture of Release to No.

[image: Set Build Active Architecture to No]