# Uploading flutter app to AppStore gives App.framework does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, ipa, info-plist

I have successfully generated .ipa for app store connect but when Uploading to App Store Connect from XCode in the validation phase I am getting this error `ERROR ITMS-90208: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle myApp.app/Frameworks/App.framework does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist."`

I have tried
[ERROR ITMS-90208: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle <your.app> does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518765/error-itms-90208-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-your-app-does-not-support-the-mi)

https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg/issues/18

these solutions but didn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am able to solve this by specifying minimumOsVersion in `myApp.app/Frameworks/App.framework`'s info.plist file (Please make sure that it is not the global info.plist file it is generated after creating the build)

Comment: I am getting this error and I tried all of the above and it still did not work. Anything else you did to fix it?

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem.
To fix, I did this steps:

1. `Flutter clean`
2. Change files AppFrameworkInfo.plist (/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist) and Info.plist (/ios/Flutter/Flutter.Framework/Info.plist)
3. Put version 9.0 on code `<key>MinimumOSVersion</key> <string>9.0</string>`

Than I run `flutter build ios --release`

Comment: The only needed file is `AppFrameworkInfo.plist` because the others are automatically replaced every build

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me. Saved me twice! <3

Answer (score 20):

Step-1: Open your Flutter project in XCode

Step-2: Change minimum OS version like this for your project:
[image: preview]

Step-3: Change minimum OS version like this for Flutter Framework
[image: preview]

Step-4: Archive and Publish your app.

Here is the [official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios#updating-the-apps-deployment-version) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter has enforced the minimum plugin version of 11 in flutter version 3.3

[Flutter 3.3. Release notes](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-3.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

My case:

1. Check ios/Podfile you can see this: platform :ios, '13.0' (or other number)
2. Open Xcode => Runner/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo change MinimumOSVersion to 13.0. Do the same for Runner/Runner/Info.

[image]