# Showing Recent Messages Package.resolved file is corrupted or malformed; fix or delete the file to continue: unsupported schema version 2

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I cloned the project and the SPM was broken there. I removed the package dependency, but the error remains. And when I add the dependency again - I get this error.
As I understand it, swiftpm was not in .gitignore.
How can I solve this problem and add a dependency?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3c38.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiWqa.png)

I saw this topic, but these steps didn't help me:
[Package.resolved file is corrupted or malformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67185817/package-resolved-file-is-corrupted-or-malformed)