# How can I resolve 'Package.resolved' file corruption in a Swift package and prevent it from recurring?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

While working on a Swift project, I ran into a problem with a corrupted or malformed "Package.resolved" file. I get the following problem when I try to resolve dependencies:

```
Package.resolved file is corrupted or malformed; fix or delete the file to continue: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unexpected character '<' around line 8, column 2." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character '<' around line 8, column 2., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=184})))
```

I do not found the package.resolve file in my project directory, so that I can delete the file or fix the problem manually.

Despite attempting conventional fixes such as clearing the package cache and updating to the most recent versions of the packages, the issue has not been resolved. I need more in-depth troubleshooting recommendations to figure out how to fix this problem.

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69389411/9223839) helpful?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for your kind response. I followed these steps before posting here. It works for once. When I close Xcode and run the project again, the problem occurs again. I am using Xcode 15.0.1. And there are more problems in the RXSwift package, too. Before updating Xcode the problems ware not happening