# How to fix app does not support minimum version specified error

Tags: ios, xamarin, version, bundle, testflight

I have an iOS Forms app that up to now been building and successfully being uploaded to TestFlight with a deployment target of 15.4.

I have a requirement to support devices from v14+, so I set the the deployment target to 14.0 and built. When I now upload (using Transporter) I get the following error: -

**Asset validation failed (90208)
Invalid bundle. The bundle xxxxx.iOS.app does not support the minimum OS version specified in the info.plist.**

What am I missing? Only thing I can think of is to install an earlier Xamarin sdk on the mac and set the SDK version to use that. Is that the fix?

Thanks

Comment: Possible solution from similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518765/error-itms-90208-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-your-app-does-not-support-the-mi

Comment: You probably need to update the [SDK version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/compiling-for-different-devices?tabs=macos#sdk-options) as well

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.